# algorithm guaranteed to converge for convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, computational-mathematics, newton-raphson

I have a multi-variate convex function, and I want to find its global minimum. We know there is one and only one minimum.

Is there any algorithm which is guaranteed to converge to the minimum starting from an arbitrary initial point?

How about the Newton method?

ps. The function is smooth.

Comment: Newton's method finds roots, not minima. Is $f$ differentiable? If so, then [Gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) might be a good algorithm to go with. One can guarantee convergence if $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz, and a suitable step size (in the article) is chosen.

Comment: Newton’s method *can* be used to find minima. Since you’re looking for extrema of an objective function, this is equivalent of finding the zeros of its derivative - so Newton’s method applies. The OP mentioned that the function is convex but gave no information about differentiability. Assuming the function is twice differentiable, Newton’s method can work (with caveats). Gradient descent, Levenberg-Marquardt, BFGS and also derivative-free methods will work no problem on a convex function. If derivatives are available, second-order quasi-Newton methods (I.e. BFGS) will likely converge faster.